# represent the following sentence by predicate calculus well formed formulas

Tags: predicate-logic

A computer system is intelligent if it can perform a task which if performed by human, requires intelligence

Answer (score 1):

$ \forall x (( Mx \land (\exists y ((Ty \land \forall z (( Hz \land zRy) \to Iz)) \land xRy))) \to Ix) $

where

```
  M is a predicate '_is a computer system'
  H                '_is a human'
  I                '_is intelligent' 
  T                '_ is a task'
  R is a relation  '_can perform_'
```